# How to do string.contains(string) for languages other than English?

Tags: java, android, unicode

What is the problem with following code? Why Tamil words are not getting matched?

```
List<String> nonUni = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"aa", "bb", "cc"});

if( nonUni.contains("aa")) {
    // true;
}

List<String> uniArr = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"அகில்", "முகில்", "மதி"});

if( uniArr.contains("அகில்")) {
    // false;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, I tried to run your code and it works correctly.

Comment: Runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Maybe better is to use unicode String, than it will be independent from your IDE settings

Comment: Running fine on my Eclipse Juno IDE also

Comment: Sorry for not informing earlier. The problem occurs inside Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.jasypt.util.password.BasicPasswordEncryptor;

public class Check {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> nonUni = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"aa", "bb", "cc"});

        if( nonUni.contains("aa")) {
            // true;
            System.out.println("Its work");
        }

        List<String> uniArr = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"அகில்", "முகில்", "மதி"});

        if( uniArr.contains("அகில்")) {
            // false;
            System.out.println("Its work");
        }     
    }
}
```

Its work perfectly

In Eclipse change properties >> Resource >> TextFileEncoding 
select Others and select UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry for not informing earlier. The problem occurs inside Android phone.